# Can I make the Photos screen saver in Vista display the file's name?

Tags: windows-vista, screensaver, filenames

The photos screen saver in XP allowed showing the file name but I can't find this option in Vista. I have three kids who looked almost identical at the same ages and the filename is sometimes the only way I can tell which child it is :o/ `</bad-parent>`

Comment: The only way you can tell my sister and me apart in childhood pictures is if you remember which of us owned which item of clothing, or parted her hair on that side, or something similar. ...Of course, we're identical twins, so this is perhaps not terribly surprising. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there's no such option and there's no way of changing this behavior; it's hardcoded in the screensaver.